# What is a Croupier's Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Croupier's Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Croupier's }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2018.03.05}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{GOTHS}&\text{HIPSTERS}\\ \hline
\text{FUTON}&\text{TATAMI}\\ \hline
\text{TRASHED}&\text{SOBER}\\ \hline
\text{CONSOLES}&\text{COMPUTERS}\\ \hline
\text{OLDIE}&\text{GOLDIE}\\ \hline
\text{HATERS}&\text{LOVERS}\\ \hline
\text{TASER}&\text{MACE}\\ \hline
\text{STRAYS}&\text{STAYS}\\ \hline
\text{BASED}&\text{DEBASED}\\ \hline
\text{GENRE}&\text{SUBGENRE}\\ \hline
\text{WIDER}&\text{NARROWER}\\ \hline
\text{FAULTS}&\text{STRENGTHS}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Croupier's Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples, there are more of both Croupier's Words™ and Not Croupier's Words™.

CSV version:

```
GOTHS,HIPSTERS
FUTON,TATAMI
TRASHED,SOBER
CONSOLES,COMPUTERS
OLDIE,GOLDIE
HATERS,LOVERS
TASER,MACE
STRAYS,STAYS
BASED,DEBASED
GENRE,SUBGENRE
WIDER,NARROWER
FAULTS,STRENGTHS
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A Croupier's Word™

> can be used to form a new word by cutting it in half (with the first half receiving the extra letter if the length is odd) and interleaving the two halves, similar to the way a croupier cuts a deck of cards and interleaves the halves to shuffle.

For example, **TRASHED** is one because

> interleaving **TRAS** and **HED** yields **THREADS**.

For completeness,

> the shuffled words are
> GHOST
> FOUNT
> THREADS
> COOLNESS
> OILED
> HEARTS
> TEARS
> SATYRS
> BEADS
> GREEN
> WEIRD
> FLATUS.

Comment: Yup, that's it, exactly. Looking at the edit history of your answer, I'm super impressed: looks like you got the answer first, and only afterwards linked it with the title! That wasn't supposed to be possible at all! :-)

Comment: @Bass If the correct answer has been posted, remember to accept it. ;-) (just posting this in case it was too early to do so back then)